# Regarding Asaph (אָ֫סָ֥ף ), why do digital versions of KJV Bible remove his name from Psalms 73-83?

Tags: psalms, textual-criticism, kjv, bible-versions

Regarding Asaph (אָ֫סָ֥ף), why do certain online KJV texts remove his name from Psalms 73-83, such as [Bible Gateway's](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ps+73%3A1-Ps+83%3A18&version=KJV)?

If we only read the KJV, the Tehillim (Psalms) may appear to be written by King David. However if we read the Tanakh, we find authorship of Tehillim (Psalms) 73-83 is ascribed to Asaph of 1 Chronicles 16:37. We find in Asaph's name in the Hebrew Psalms but not in the English Psalms of KJV Bible.

> Tehillim 73:1 [MT]:
> A song of Asaph. Truly God is good to Israel, to the pure of heart. (מִזְמ֗וֹר לְאָ֫סָ֥ף אַ֚ךְ ט֖וֹב לְיִשְׂרָאֵ֥ל אֱלֹהִ֗ים לְבָרֵ֥י לֵבָֽב )

> Psalm 73:1 [KJV]:
> Truly God is good to Israel, even to such as are of a clean heart. ([Bible Gateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%2073&version=KJV))

Is this a textual choice they made for some editions of the KJV, or are there manuscripts that do not include the titles?

Comment: Certain (online or electronic) editions of the Bible (not just of the traditional King James Version) make it their mission in life to remove all chapter and paragraph  titles, as well as epistle endings, since these are **usually not** in the **original** manuscripts, the obvious **exception** being the psalms. **Indiscriminate** removal then leads to situations such as the one presented in this post. In print, this is, in my experience, significantly less common; unless, of course, one were to actually print such censored copies of scripture.

Comment: Thanks, Lucian!  Why would "Bible Gateway" omit words from verses even if they serve as paragraph titles? Is there any source to explain such omissions? - Your feedback has really helped to update this question now specifically related to online versions of KJV.

Comment: @Dottard - The question has been updated to reflect digital versions of KJV Bible instead of the 1611 printed KJV to help clarify the point.

Comment: [BibleGateWay idenifies the KJV they use](https://www.biblegateway.com/versions/King-James-Version-KJV-Bible/) as "*the 1987 printing*".

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer and to remove unnecessary asides about Asaph in other parts of the Bible. Please don't roll it back.

Comment: The titles of the Psalms are different from all other section headings in the Bible as they're actually part of the text. This is an interesting observation and I'd love to know why they removed the headings from those chapters. Are there manuscripts that don't have them? Was it just a mistake in one edition which was then digitised?

Comment: @enegue not sure about that story. The text matches the Project Gutenberg text.

Comment: @David Well, here's a howdy-do! Someone has removed that story. It must have been offensive.

Comment: @enegue Are you sure? I can still see the link and it mentions 1987.

Comment: @David I thought you were referring to the comment I made following the one above about how the attributions to the Psalms puzzle me. Someone has deleted it. I asked, *Why isn't לְאָ֫סָ֥ף מִזְמ֗וֹר rendered as 'to/for Asaph (a) psalm',  i.e. a psalm given to/written for Asaph?*", which seems to be the plain meaning of the Hebrew. As far as '1987' is concerned, that is just what Biblegateway has stated concerning the text they are providing.

Comment: @enegue I added a paragraph to my answer to explain about different numbering.

Answer (score 2):

There may be confusion as to what forms part of the text or not. This arises because the superscriptions in the King James are just part of the regular text in the Hebrew Bible, though they are presumably not part of the verse (as in poetry). These are sometimes part of verse 1 in the MT which becomes a superscription in the King James and are sometimes a whole extra verse and the MT has one added to the number of each verse.

But for what reason it was omitted from the biblegateway text that appears to come from the Project Gutenberg text, I don’t know. Texts I use suffer the same fault due to my laziness and incompleteness of processing the text.

You might have more success with the [AKJV text on biblegateway](https://www.biblegateway.com/versions/Authorized-King-James-Version-AKJV-Bible/) but this looks like it may have different restrictions.

The text I would tentatively recommend for accuracy is the [Pure Bible Search](https://www.purebiblesearch.com/) text.

The numerical signatures in the Authorised King James Version, suggest there should be 789,629 words plus 1034 in superscriptions making a total of 790,663 words.

Interestingly, the numbers 789 and 629 turn up in in shCherbak’s patterns in his paper:

shCherbak, Vladimir I. "Arithmetic inside the universal genetic code." *BioSystems* 70.3 (2003): 187-209.

which is more plainly exposed in: http://www.whatabeginning.com/Misc/Genetics/Genetics_VS.htm